# What if the admin sets "AllowOverride None" some day?

Tags: apache, unix, webserver

I want to password protect a directory on a web server. I make the .htaccess and .htpasswd files and everything works.

What if some day, the admin comes along and sets "AllowOverride None" in httpd.conf? Does that immediately make all of my secrets visible to the whole wide web?

Is there another way to password protect files on a web server without having to store a password in plain text and doesn't leave the protection at the mercy of an admin?

Answer (score 0):

Place the files outside of your webroot and use a serverside (scripting) language like php or python and make/use a login system. The script can access to your files outside your webroot and send it to your browser.